# JQuery Ajax bad request to RESTfull API

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, rest

I'm trying to authenticate against demo webservices developed by a colleague of mine. 
the Cross-origin resource sharing is allowed and works perfectly if I try to call from Advanced rest client plugin in Chrome. 
but when I try to access with the code I get 500 server error

```
.ajax({ 
        type : "POST",  
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'CANTPOSTTHISURL/rest/session',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",      
        data: JSON.stringify({"username": "admin", "password": "admin" }),
        success: function(response)
        {
            console.log(response); 
        },
        error: function (data, status) {
            console.log( 'Sample of error data:', status );
            console.log("readyState: "+data.readyState+"\nstatus: "+data.status+"\nresponseText: "+data.responseText);
        },
        complete: function(xhr, status ) {
            console.log( 'COMPLETE');
        }   
  });
```

the errors I get are:

```
    OPTIONS CANTPOSTTHISURL/rest/session 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js:8475
send jquery.js:8475
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:7930
authenticate wts.js:5
(anonymous function) wts.js:27
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3045
elemData.handle jquery.js:2721
jQuery.event.trigger jquery.js:2957
(anonymous function) jquery.js:3639
jQuery.extend.each jquery.js:631
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery.js:253
jQuery.fn.extend.trigger jquery.js:3638
H jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js:2
I jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js:2
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3045
elemData.handle jquery.js:2721
OPTIONS CANTPOSTTHISURL/rest/session Invalid HTTP status code 500 jquery.js:8475
send jquery.js:8475
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:7930
authenticate wts.js:5
(anonymous function) wts.js:27
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3045
elemData.handle jquery.js:2721
jQuery.event.trigger jquery.js:2957
(anonymous function) jquery.js:3639
jQuery.extend.each jquery.js:631
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery.js:253
jQuery.fn.extend.trigger jquery.js:3638
H jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js:2
I jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js:2
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3045
elemData.handle jquery.js:2721
XMLHttpRequest cannot load CANTPOSTTHISURL/rest/session. Invalid HTTP status code 500 index.html:1
Sample of error data: error wts.js:16
readyState: 0
status: 0
responseText:  wts.js:17
COMPLETE
```

and the headers:

```
Request URL:CANTPOSTTHISURL/rest/session
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:CANTPOSTTHISURL
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:8020
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8020/ppm/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:close
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Mon, 31 Mar 2014 13:24:36 GMT
Server:Wildfly 8
Set-Cookie:GEAR=local-53185956500446bd39000020; path=/
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:Undertow 1
ConsoleSearch
```

I think it is the data I'm sending but I also tried with '{"username": "admin", "password": "admin" }' or {"username": "admin", "password": "admin" } but nothing changes.
an important remark: I can only do POST or OPTION requests so no jsonp 
thank you

Comment: Well, a `500` response code means something went wrong on the server side. Without seeing that code, going to be near impossible to help

Answer (score -2):

I don't think You need to use stringify method.

I am using below format, and its working for me:

```
url : "http://localhost:9200/" + eleName + "/_suggest",
type : "POST",
dataType : "json",
ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data:"{\"result\":{\"text\":\"" + request.term + "\",\"completion\":{\"size\" :10,\"field\":\"name_suggest\"}}}",
```

Try with String in JSON Format.

Comment: thank you, I changed to below but still not working. 
data: "{\"username\":\"admin\",\"password\":\"admin\"}",

Comment: sorry I disagree. contentType as an ajax call is written this way otherwise it won't be able to send it and it fires a 415 error